# How to install Spyder 4 IDE on Raspberry OS

Tags: raspberry-pi, spyder

I can install Spyder 3 IDE on Raspberry OS 32-bit easily using:

```
sudo apt-get install spyder3
```

However I can't find a way to install Spyder 4. I've tried:

```
pip3 install spyder
```

But it shows an error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyls-black>=0.4.6 (from spyder) (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.2.0,0.2.1,0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5) No matching distribution found for pyls-black>=0.4.6 (from spyder)
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please try with `pip install spyder==4.1.5`, although I can't say if that would help.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work too. i've got a similar error:  
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipykernel>=5.1.3; python_version > "2" (from spyder-kernels<1.10.0,>=1.9.4->spyder==4.1.5) (from versions: 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.5.0, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.7.0, 4.8.0, 4.8.1, 4.8.2, 4.9.0, 4.10.0, 4.10.1) No matching distribution found for ipykernel>=5.1.3; python_version > "2" (from spyder-kernels<1.10.0,>=1.9.4->spyder==4.1.5) `

Comment: Sorry, it seems not possible to install Spyder in Raspberry Pi with pip.